# How can i use a destroy function with a route that is composed Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

***I tried to delete some file of my database from the aplication using a destroy function but doesn't work, it works with routes that are simples but no composed,its for school***

- Below i will let the code of my route, the `destroy function()` , how i tried to invocate the function and my `index function()`
- Give me the Error:`Missing required parameters for [Route: asociados.destroy] [URI: eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/asociados/{asociado}]`

***Route***

```php
Route::resource('/eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/asociados', 'miembroController');
```

***`Destroy function()`***

```php
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        $miembro=Miembro::find($id);
        $miembro->delete();
        return back()->with('Evento eliminado');
    }
```

*** `Index function()`***

```php
 public function index(Request $request, $id_evento,$id_miembro){
        $miembros = DB::select(DB::raw(
            "SELECT id_miembro, razon_social, denominacion_comercial, web,
                    rif
            FROM miembro
           " ));

        return view ('home.miembro')->with('miembros', $miembros)->with('id_evento', $id_evento)->with('id_miembro', $id_miembro);
    }
```

***Code in the html of how i tried to invocate the `destroy function()`***

```html
                <td>
                    <form action={{ route('asociados.destroy', ['miembro' => $item->id_miembro]) }} 
                    method="POST" class="d-inline">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
                    </form>

                </td>
```

Comment: You have two variables in your route definition but you're only passing one variable to the route function, have you tried passing the `evento` id as well?

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: What does the URL action generated by the route() function look like when it's actually rendered on the page?

Comment: Looks like this`/eventos/1/miembros/1/asociados`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give to the `route` helper also the event id:

```
            <td>
                <form action={{ route('asociados.destroy', ['eventos'=> $id_evento ,'miembro' => $item->id_miembro]) }} 
                method="POST" class="d-inline">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
                </form>

            </td>
```